Mint "display zoom" with just mouse (one-handed)
I got nothing useful a few years ago when I asked about Simulate keyboard input using mouse, but I eventually cracked that one myself with input-remapper.
I now have input-remapper dummying up the unused mouse PgUp/PgDn buttons to emulate entering my password / pressing the space bar, so I can do almost everything I want with my Linux Mint "home entertainment" PC using just just the mouse in my right hand.
Almost everything. If I want to zoom the display, I have to reach over with my left hand to hold down Shift (defined as the "modifier" for the mouse wheel zoom function).
I'm now using all the individual buttons on my Logitech MX Anywhere 3 mouse, and I don't think input-remapper supports things like "long" press, or pressing two buttons at once. And toggling "keyboard shift state" doesn't look like something input-remapper can do anyway. Is there another way to override existing scroll / volume functionality for the mouse wheel, without having to use the keyboard?
